# Divergence of an Integral on a finite interval $\to$ Divergence on infinite interval?

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence

Let $a$ be a finite number ($a \in \Bbb R$)

Assuming that $$\int_1^af(x)dx$$ **Does not converge**

Does it mean that

$$\int_0^\infty f(x)dx$$

**Does not converge** as well?

This is since $$[1,a]\subset [0,\infty)$$

Answer (score 2):

**Definition**:

We say a function defined on a finite interval $[a,b]$ is *improper Riemann integrable* if there is a partition $P = \{a=x_0, x_1, x_2 \cdots x_n =b\}$ such that for all $\epsilon, \delta$ sufficiently small, $f$ is proper Riemann integrable on $[x_{i-1} + \delta, x_i-\epsilon]$ where $1 \leq i \leq n$ and the limit

$$I(x_i) \stackrel{\rm def}{=}\lim_{(\epsilon, \delta) \to (0,0)} \int_{x_{i-1} + \delta}^{x_i - \epsilon} f(x) \ dx$$

exists as a finite number. Then the *improper Riemann integral* is

$$\int_a^b f(x) dx \stackrel{\rm def}{=} \sum_{i=1}^n I(x_i) $$

Note that if $b<a$ then we simply consider $$-\int_b^a f(x) dx$$

Furthermore, the improper $\int_a^a f(x) \ dx$ is always $0$.

**Lemma**

The improper Riemann integral is additive. In other words, we have

$$\int_a^b f(x) dx = \int_a^c f(x) dx + \int_c^b f(x) dx$$

assuming at least one side of the equation is well-defined. This proof is  a straightforward application of the definition assuming $a \leq c \leq b$. If improper integrability on $[a,b]$ is assumed, then consider the partition $P \cup \{c\}$ and divide it into two separate partitions. Since sums, limits and proper Riemann integrals are additive, the claim immediately follows. On the other hand, if we have partitions for $[a,c]$ and $[c,b]$, then consider their union as the partition for $[a,b]$.

Note that if $a \leq b \leq c$ (or, indeed, any permutation of the order of $a,b,c$) the above equation remains true. The proof of this is completely analogous to the corresponding proof for the normal Riemann integral. It has to do with how we define integrals $\int_a^b f$ where $b<a$ above.

**Extension of Definition**

For intervals of the form $[a, \infty)$, we say that $f$ is *improper Riemann integrable*

if the limit $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \int_a^x f(t) \ dt$$ exists as a finite number. The integral inside the limit is an improper Riemann integral on $[a,x]$ which we assume exists. We can define similarly for intervals of the form $(-\infty, b]$.

**Proof**

Below I will prove the contrapositive of your statement. We will strictly work with the improper Riemann integral as defined above, for full generality. The integral

$$\int_0^{\infty} f(x) \ dx$$ is the limit

$$\lim_{u \to \infty} \int_0^{u} f(x)\  dx$$

In particular, this implies that $f$ must be improper Riemann integrable on $[0, u]$ for all sufficiently large $u>a$ where $a$ is any given positive number. Hence, we get that

$$\int_0^{u}  f(x) \ dx = \int_0^1 f(x) dx + \int_1^a f(x) dx + \int_a^u f(x) dx$$

by additivity. Since the integral on the left is well-defined, the three integrals on the right are also well-defined.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\int_{1}^{a}f(x)dx=+\infty$,$a<b<\infty$ and  $\int_{b}^{c}f(x)dx=-\infty$, then $\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)dx$ may become undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You can write

$$\int_0^\infty f(x)\,\mathrm dx=\int_0^1 f(x)\,\mathrm dx+\int_1^a f(x)\,\mathrm dx+\int_a^\infty f(x)\,\mathrm dx\tag1$$

Without lose of generality assume that $\int_0^1 f$ is Riemann-integrable (in the standard sense, that is, that the integral is a proper integral of Riemann with defined value in $\Bbb R$).

Suppose also without lose of generality that $\int_1^a f=\lim_{y\to a^-}\int_1^y f=\infty$ is a non-convergent improper integral. Then $(1)$ cannot converge as an improper integral because

$$\begin{align}\int_0^\infty f(x)\,\mathrm dx&=\int_0^1 f(x)\,\mathrm dx+\lim_{y\to a^-}\int_1^y f(x)\,\mathrm dx+\lim_{z\to a^+}\int_z^c f(x)\,\mathrm dx+\lim_{w\to\infty}\int_c^wf(x)\,\mathrm dx\\&=\int_0^1 f(x)\,\mathrm dx+\infty+\lim_{z\to a^+}\int_z^c f(x)\,\mathrm dx+\lim_{w\to\infty}\int_c^wf(x)\,\mathrm dx\\&\equiv\text{ undefined or diverges to infinity}\end{align}$$

However in these cases is possible that the Cauchy principal value is defined, that is

$$\operatorname{PV}\int_0^\infty f(x)\,\mathrm dx:=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\left[\int_0^{a-\epsilon} f(x)\,\mathrm dx+\int_{a+\epsilon}^{a+1/\epsilon} f(x)\,\mathrm dx\right]\in\Bbb R$$

regardless of the kind of convergence of $\int_1^a f$.